# How can I show all documents from my firebase collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firebase called "ChatRooms" it stores documents for each chat room created in my app. Right now I'm trying to display the name of each chat room on the page, but I'm having trouble getting the text to actually show up on the page.

here is my code.

```
  const [chatRoomData, setChatRoomData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() =>{
    const getAllChatRoomDocs = async () => {
      const chatRoomDocRef = await getDocs(collection(dataBase, `ChatRooms`));
      const chatRooms = [];
      chatRoomDocRef.forEach((doc) => {
        chatRooms.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
      })
      console.log(chatRooms);
      setChatRoomData(chatRooms);
    };
    getAllChatRoomDocs();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <div className="chats-container">
          <header className='header-container'> 
            <h1 className="header">Your Chats</h1>
          </header>
            <div>
              <ul>
                {Object.keys(chatRoomData || {}).map(item =>(
                  <li>{item.chatRoom}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

the console log returns all the document data back to me in an array.
[image]

and I see list elements being created for each chat room. In the 'elements' section in the chrome dev tools.

[image]

here is an image of my firebase database.
[image]

I just don't understand why the list elements aren't displaying on the page as intended.